# IIS URL Rewrite will not work with Integrated mode (but all other action types do)

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I have an IIS rewrite rule that I'm trying to use.
When I set the Action to ‘redirect’ its working fine. Likewise, if I select Custom response and set some arbitrary status code, I’m getting that back in the HTTP response, so I know the rule is matching for my URL. However, I need to rewrite this (to act as a reverse proxy) but as soon as I change the action to ‘Rewrite’ it doesn’t take effect.

I have installed the Application Request Routing Module and enabled the proxy under ‘Server proxy settings’ (as per this page http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing).

I’ve tried everything from restarting the site(s), the server, IIS, the W3p process and nothing takes effect. I've added the rule at a server level as required and confirmed in the ApplicationHost.config file that it is there and correct.

Any ideas what isn't causing this to fire?
I've seen a few similar posts here on SO, but none of them either have a solution or work for me in this instance.

**EDIT: OK, so if I change the application pool from integrated to classic, the rule seems to fire (which is weird as the rule is at a server level!?!). However, My site requires integrated mode to function. Anyone know whats going on here?**